# PHP preg_split() not capturing the split in the string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-split

I'm trying to use a regex with preg_split to separate a url from a string:

```
    $body = "blah blah blah http://localhost/tomato/veggie?=32";
    $regex = "(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)";
    $url = preg_split($regex, $body);
```

The resulting array is:

```
    array(2) (
    [0] => (string) blah blah blah 
    [1] => (string))
```

I would like to return:

```
    array(2) (
    [0] => (string) blah blah blah 
    [1] => (string) http://localhost/tomato/veggie?=32)
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding another set of brackets to capture the entire URL with an optional preg_split() parameter:

```
$regex = "((((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+))";
$url = preg_split($regex, $body, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "blah blah blah "
  [1]=>
  string(34) "http://localhost/tomato/veggie?=32"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "http://"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "ht"
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: you could add 2 non-cature groups to clean the output up like this `(((?:(?:f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+))` - takes `[2]` and `[3]` from the array. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because you are splitting on a URL, not on a delimiter.  The delimiter in this case is the "last space before ftp or http":

```
$body = "blah blah blah http://localhost/tomato/veggie?=32";
$regex = '/\s+(?=(f|ht)tp:\/\/)/';
$url = preg_split($regex, $body);
```

To break down the regular expression:

```
\s+ - One or more spaces
(?=...) - Positive look-ahead (match stuff in this group, but don't consume it)
(f|ht)tp:\/\/ - ftp:// or http://
```

Comment: If a word came after the URL, like `blah blah blah http://localhost/tomato/veggie?=32 test`, it would be added into the part with the URL. `array([0]=>'blah blah blah ',[1]=>'http://localhost/tomato/veggie?=32 test')`

Comment: Indeed. Luckily that doesn't apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that your regex is not [delimited](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (i.e. not surrounded by slashes).

The second issue is that given the sample output you provided, you may want to look into using [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) instead.

Try this, see if it's what you want:

```
$body = "blah blah blah http://localhost/tomato/veggie?=32";
$regex = "/^(.*?)((?:(?:f|ht)tps?:\/\/).+)/i";
preg_match($regex, $body, $url);
print_r($url);
```